# How to make a Mono/Winforms application look like a modern application?

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

When I write a application in Mono with the Winforms GUI toolkit, it looks pretty native (ofcourse, because it is.), but it looks old, like an application that was made for Windows 98. I searched in Visual Studio projects, into the GUI code generated by the designer, but I don't see what the difference is. The VS designer also imports System.Windows.Forms, but it looks nice and modern, not old.

Back in the days, when I was codign in Visual Basic (not the .Net kind), we did that with a manifest file, that worked nice (on Windows XP, Vista or 7 wasn't released back then.). But I doubt that a manifest file is the solution here, as I cannot find anything relating to this on the internet.

So, how do I make a Mono application look like a modern Winforms application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles(); //Do this before creating your first form.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx

Comment: From the mono [FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Winforms): "Visual Styles are not currently supported on Linux/OSX. It is fine to call EnableVisualStyles () on these platforms, it just won't have any effect."

Comment: Correct (You didn't specify targeting non-windows in your question). You can only use Visual Styles on windows. If you want a 'nice' looking user interface on Linux/Mac OS then you have to use GTK instead of Winforms.

Comment: I'm not the one who posted the question. I just assumed he was targeting Linux, because he says in VS (under windows) it works and looks good and IIRC VS automatically enables visual styles.

Comment: Thank you, that line did it!
And indeed, I'm not specifying other OS's with Winforms, I like to have native applications.